# How to build an Eclipse project from command line without any pre-existing workspace?

Tags: eclipse, continuous-integration, eclipse-cdt

I have a C source repository with an Eclipse project (.project and .cproject files  at the top-level). I need to build that project from the command line, so that it is integrated with our CI system.

I know that I can build an Eclipse workspace from the command line (or a specific project within a workspace), as explained here: [C++ eclipse project automatic build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598087/c-eclipse-project-automatic-build-server) and here: [Build Eclipse Java Project from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line/1433396)
But what I would like to do is to build a project without having any workspace. It sounds pretty ugly to commit a workspace (.metadata folder) into the source repository.

Is there other command line options for building a project without having to specify a workspace? If not, is it possible to generate the workspace "on the fly"?

Answer (score 3):

I eventually found a solution following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8908262/6289487

I was using *-data* command line option, the trick is to use *-import*.

Comment: AFAICT you ned `-data` too to tell it where to create the temporary/new workspace. This can, however, be an empty directory.